# How to find raws that meet certain conditions by comparing raws (with the same value in a specific column) in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, find, rows

I have a dataframe that looks like the one below.

**I would like to get rows that meet the conditions I am looking for, comparing values in multiple columns between/among rows that have the same value in a specific column.**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID':[750, 1135, 1403, 7144,7144,7144,10424,10984,10984,12710,12710,
                              7151,7151,7152,13249,13249,13249,9303,9303,9461,9461,9478,9478,
                              9478,9710,9710],
               'Age':[25,36,63,56,56,56,25,45,45,38,38,16,16,73,50,50,50,41,41,63,63,22,22,22,
                      34,34],
              'Subscription_Product':['Product A','Product B','Product C','Product D',
                                      'Product C','Product A','Product C','Product B',
                                      'Product A','Product D','Product A','Product A',
                                      'Product C','Product D','Product B','Product A',
                                      'Product A','Product D','Product A','Product A',
                                      'Product C','Product A','Product B','Product A',
                                      'Product A','Product D'],
              'Entry_Date':['2011-09-25','2015-08-25','2015-10-25','1999-06-26',
                                         '1995-06-29','2002-08-25','2001-07-22','1995-01-29',
                                         '1997-05-10','2012-10-10','2015-06-10','1995-01-15',
                                         '2002-02-24','2019-04-25','1995-01-19','2001-02-25',
                                         '2014-03-15','2002-07-24','1997-03-19','2001-03-14',
                                         '2005-02-23','2001-02-02','2007-12-18','2010-12-18',
                                         '2013-01-09','2013-05-15'],
              'Cancellation_Date':['','','','','','','','','','','2002-08-30','','','',
                                   '2008-02-25','','','','','','','2011-12-18','','','','']})
```

[Click to see the dataframe printed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyjzE.png)

**I am trying to search for customers who, while subscribing to one or more product already, has/had made additional subscription to/subscribed to 'Product A' later. At the point when the customer added subscription for 'Product A', the customer must have or had been actively subscribed to a product already.**

In other words, from the dataframe, I would like to get the rows, index numbers, or Customer IDs where :

(1) have the same [Customer ID]

(2) and must have 'Product A' for subscription; This means that if a customer has/had 'Product A' as well as other subscription products, the subscription start date([Entry_Date]) for 'Product A' must be greater than that of other product subscriptions he has/had.

(3) when a customer has a subscription already cancelled, if the cancellation date of the customer's old subscription is greater than the start date of his 'Product A' subscription, it counts. (because it means he subscribed to Product A while he was actively subscribed to some other product)

To give you an example, the customer with Customer ID '10984' additionally made a subscription to Product A while he already had some other one. And that customer(the rows or the Customer ID) is one of what I am looking for.

For another example,  the customer with id# '9478' subscribed to 'Product A' before he cancelled his subscription for 'Product B', which means at the point when he subscribed to 'Product A', his was actively subscribed to a product. Then, he is also one of what I am looking for.

I tried to use **.loc**, but was not enough to get what I need. Maybe use loop?

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try using dataframe[condition]? For example dataframe[dataframe['Subscription_Product'] == 'Product A'] will give you all the rows that are subscribed to Product A.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried, and it was not enough for what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a function like the one provided below.

The function ignores every customer who hasn't made more than one subscription and, in addition to that, it ignores those customers who haven't purchase at least one subscription to "*Product A*" (this improves the efficiency of the program in case you want to use it with a dataframe with many rows, although for the example provided it won't make much of a difference efficiency-wise).

After that, it loops through the resulting dataframe to see which customers match the conditions that you are looking for.

```
def findSpecialCustomer(df):
    # Create dataframe with only repeated customers 
    aux = df[df.duplicated(subset=['Customer_ID'], keep = False)].reset_index(drop = True)
    # List of customers who acquired "Product A"
    listOfRepeated = pd.unique(df[df.Subscription_Product.eq('Product A')]['Customer_ID'])
    # Discard from our previous dataframe the customer who didn't acquired "Product A"
    aux = aux[aux.Customer_ID.isin(listOfRepeated)]
    
    # Empty list that will contain the list of customers that we are looking for
    customersFound = []
    
    # Iterate for each customer in our filtered dataframe
    for i in pd.unique(aux['Customer_ID']):
        # Auxiliar boolean to check if the customer has a subscription other than "Product A"
        prevSubscription = False
        # Auxiliar String to check if it has cancellation date and compare it
        cancellation_date = ""
        # Iterate through each product that a same customer has acquired
        for index, row in aux[aux.Customer_ID.eq(i)].iterrows():
            # If the customer has acquired a product different than "Product A" set boolean to True
            if(row['Subscription_Product']!='Product A'):
                prevSubscription = True
                # In case Cancellation_Date exists, save it in auxiliar variable
                if (row['Cancellation_Date'] != ""):
                   cancellation_date = row['Cancellation_Date']
            # If the customer has bought a product different than A before and it is buying product A
            if((row['Subscription_Product']=='Product A')&(prevSubscription == True)):
                # If the customer has a cancellation date in a product different than product A
                if (cancellation_date != ""):
                    # If the subscription to the other product hasn't been cancelled by the time 
                    # the customer acquires "Subscription A", then add it to our list
                    if (cancellation_date>row['Entry_Date']):
                        # Save customer in auxiliar list
                        customersFound.append(row['Customer_ID'])
                else:
                    # Save customer in auxiliar list
                    customersFound.append(row['Customer_ID'])
    
    return customersFound

# Our list of the ID's of the customers with the conditions we are looking for
listOfUsersFound = findSpecialCustomer(df)
listOfUsersFound
Out[2]: [7144, 10984, 12710, 13249, 9303, 9478]
```

[EDIT+]
If you also want another function that returns a list with the customers which have purchased a "*Product A*" while having another subscription to another "*Product A*" you could modify the function in my previous answer like I stated in the comments. But I also recommend a slightly different approach to handle multiple cancellations.

```
def findMultipleASubscriptionCustomers(df):

# Create dataframe with customers who have more than one Product A subscription
aux = df[df.Subscription_Product == 'Product A'].groupby('Customer_ID').filter(lambda x: x.count()[['Subscription_Product']]>1)

# Empty list that will contain the list of customers that we are looking for
customersFound = []

# Iterate for each customer in our filtered dataframe
for i in pd.unique(aux['Customer_ID']):
    # Auxiliar boolean to check if it has cancellation date and compare it
    subscriptionsWithoutCancelDate = False

    #Auxiliar list to save all cancellation dates 
    listOfCancellDates = []
    # Iterate through each A product that a same customer has acquired
    for index, row in aux[aux.Customer_ID.eq(i)].iterrows():
        
        # If we've iterated through our dataframe and we've found one product A without Cancellation Date
        if(subscriptionsWithoutCancelDate==True):
            # Save customer in our final list
            customersFound.append(row['Customer_ID'])
            # break out of loop to continue with next customer
            break
        else:
            # If we've collected previously cancellation dates and our list is NOT EMPTY
            if (not listOfCancellDates):
                # If the dates in our list are ALL after the entry date of our actual subscription
                # (which means the customer purchased this A Product while having other A product)
                if all(row['Entry_Date'] < dates for dates in listOfCancellDates):
                    # Save customer in our final list
                    customersFound.append(row['Customer_ID'])
                    # break out of loop to continue with next customer
                    break
                    
            # If case Cancellation_Date exists
            if (row['Cancellation_Date'] != ""):
                # Save Cancellation Date into our list
                listOfCancellDates.append(row['Cancellation_Date'])
            else:
                # This product doesn't have a cancellation date which means that if the same 
                # customer buys another A Product (if we iterate one more time this for loop)
                # it will mean that it's buying it's SECOND A product. (We will add it to our 
                # customer list and break the loop)
                subscriptionsWithoutCancelDate=True
                
return customersFound

auxList = findMultipleASubscriptionCustomers(df)
auxList
Out[2]: [13249, 9478]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The function does work and looks incredible! I am also trying to figure out a way to find customers who bought additional Product A while had active subscription to Product A. I tried several times making a few changes to the sample data I provided and your function code (e.g. changing to row['Subscription_Product']  == 'Product A', changing prevSubscription == True/False, etc.), but did not go well. Could you please help me out with this? (Customers with Product A adding another Product A)

Comment: @eodud0582 No problem! In this case, changing the condition to `row['Subscription_Product']=='Product A'` will not be enough, because after getting into that condition it will inevitable go into our second condition `if((row['Subscription_Product']=='Product A')&(prevSubscription == True))` the resulting list will have every customers that have one A product. 
One easy solution would be to use elif. First if: `if(row['Subscription_Product']=='Product A')&(prevSubscriptionA != True)` Second if: `elif((row['Subscription_Product']=='Product A')&(prevSubscriptionA == True))`
Check my new answer!